# ggplot2 has stopped adding labels to axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

My `ggplot2` package has stopped adding information of labels and axis information to my plots. I have tried to change the themes by for example adding `+ theme_bw()` but this does not affect labels. I am using R version 4.0.3 with ggplot2 3.3.3 .

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried starting a new R session? I've seen this behaviour before when people load the ggtern package in the same session.

Comment: Incredible you could read my unwritten code! I had ggtern loaded. If you leave your response below I will choose it as the best answer. Surely this is a bug for ggtern? So incredibly difficult to debug.

Comment: Yeah ggtern overwrites some ggplot2 namespace exports, which is not best practise by any stretch of the imagination. The issue has been [reported](https://bitbucket.org/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues/13/ggtern-breaks-ggplots-plot) and is [supposedly fixed](https://twitter.com/ggtern/status/1249188285588688897?s=20), but I don't use ggtern myself so I don't know how well it works. Out of curiosity what version are you using?